# How do I make the ListView entries have centered alignment? (Android)

Tags: android, list

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

in XML, as well as

```
listView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

didn't work.

Comment: Post all your xml file please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code looks little ugly , but after you understand you can make it the way you like it.

1) Create a Layout with a TextView the way you want to display .
example  /res/layout/item_layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_view_at_custom_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

PS: notice that i used

```
android:gravity="center"
```

2) Create the List with your Data (in this case String)

```
 String strs[] = {"Good","Bag","Cute","Ugly","Hot","Cold","ETC"};
 // mList i declare it global to use it on the inner class 
 mList = Arrays.asList(strs);
```

3) Create a class extending a ArrayAdapter
i did a inner class with default Constructor notice what arguments a pass to the super();

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public MyCustomAdapter()
    {
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.item_layout,mList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView==null) convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

        TextView textViewAtCustomLayout = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_at_custom_layout);
        textViewAtCustomLayout.setText(mList.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
```

4) now set the adapter to your ListView

```
 listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter());
```

if you don't like the default Constructor you can create a constructor with arguments and pass it here.

and here is the complete code

https://github.com/adliano/SimpleListView

and this how is look like

[image: screenshot_simple_listview]

i hope this help !